Move files from SQL nvarchar to Azure Blob Storage and update URLs using Azure Data Factory
How can I use Azure Data Factory to move files stored as nvarchar in a SQL table to Azure Blob Storage and then update the corresponding rows with the new Blob URLs?

...how are you storing files in nvarchar columns? Those do not store binary data.

this is Base64String

That's horrible...

Oh, in that form it's imported from the dataverse , but thanks ever so much for your "expert" contribution!
